How do I fit a ListView in a Card without overflowing the screen in Flutter?
I am building a personal use mobile application. In this page I want to have a few Cards, and one of these cards holds an AppBar and a ListView.builder(). Ideally, once the list gets too big, the ListView is scrollable. Here's two screenshots.
I have tried wrapping my different components in Centers, Flexibles and whatevers but I'm out of my depth with this.
Here's the code of this page:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:timetablepp/objectbox.g.dart';

class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DashboardPage> createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar dashboardAppBar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Main Page'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],

      /*actions: <Widget>[
    PopupMenuButton(itemBuilder: itemBuilder)
  ],*/
    );

    Card upcomingCard = Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 2.0,
      child: ListTile(
        isThreeLine: true,
        title: Text("Upcoming"),
        subtitle: Text(
            "TODO overdue tasks, TODO due today, TODO due tomorrow\nTODO upcoming Tasks\nTODO upcoming exams"),
      ),
    );

    Card subjectsCard = Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 2.0,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          AppBar(
            title: Text("Subjects"),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 8, 
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text("TODO $index"),
                      );
                    })
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      appBar: dashboardAppBar,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: upcomingCard,
          ),
          Center(
            child: subjectsCard,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


If your SingleChildScrollView's Column has no other child then remove Column and add physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to Listview.builder widget.

@DroidFlutter this does not help. It just causes the overflow you can see in my second screenshot

Use a SingleChildScrollView for the main body and ensure the ListView.builder() inside the card scrolls independently.
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
  appBar: dashboardAppBar,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: upcomingCard,
        ),
        Center(
          child: subjectsCard,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);


I do not want my scaffolding to be scrollable. I only want my second Card's Listview to be scrollable

Try below code
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      appBar: dashboardAppBar,
      body: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: upcomingCard,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: subjectsCard,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
    );

And for listing items use code like below
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            ListTile(
              title: Text("TODO $i"),
            )
        ]),
      )


This is progress but now it shows the bottom overflow inside the card widget, like this.

I have updated my answer and replaced ListView.builder with SingleChildScrollView.

I solved by fitting  a Scaffold() inside the card.
The scaffold has an appbar:AppBar() and body:SingleChildScrollView(). The SingleChildScrollView has the contents of the card.
buildSubjectsCardNew() {
  var subjs = MainController().getAllSubjects();

  Card subjectsCard = Card(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    color: Colors.white,
    elevation: 2.0,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: buildSubjectsAppbar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < subjs.length; i++)
              buildSubjectsRow(subjs[i]),
            //Divider(height: 1,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return subjectsCard;
}

